# Cant change radio button selection - KnockoutJS

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, radio-button

I am quite new to KnockoutJS and have noticed there is quite a lot out there about radio buttons and Knockout, but unfortunately none of these could help me.

I have two radio buttons in two separate containers and can select one of them, but when selecting the other one it unfortunately doesn't change the selection even though value equals the value passed to the checked binding. Here is the simplified html:

```
  <div>
  <label>
    <input 
           type="radio" 
           name="type-1" 
           data-bind="click: function(data, event) { setUserClass('User_Classification_1', data, event); }, checked: userClass" 
           value="User_Classification_1"/>
    Some Text
  </label>
</div>
<div>
  <label>
    <input 
           type="radio" 
           name="type-1" 
           data-bind="click: function(data, event) { setUserClass('User_Classification_2', data, event);}, checked: userClass"
           value="User_Classification_2"/>
    Some Text.
  </label>
</div>
```

And here the JS :

```
    var certViewModel = function() {

        var self = this;

        self.userClass = ko.observable(undefined);

        self.setUserClass = function(uClass, data, event) {
            self.userClass(uClass);
            console.log(self.userClass());
        };
    };

  var viewModel = new certViewModel();  
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Here is an example in a fiddle that shows the problem:
https://jsfiddle.net/1vu0skpg/

**EDIT: Fixed it myself. Returning true from the click handlers fixed the issue.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just throwing in my two cents...

HTML

```
<div>
  <label>
    <input 
           type="radio" 
           name="type-1" 
           data-bind="checked: userClass" 
           value="User_Classification_1"/>
    Some Text
  </label>
</div>
<div>
  <label>
    <input 
           type="radio" 
           name="type-1" 
           data-bind="checked: userClass"
           value="User_Classification_3"/>
    Some Text.
  </label>
</div>

This is the selected radio: <strong><span data-bind="text: userClass"></strong>
```

Script

```
var certViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;

    self.userClass = ko.observable();
};

var viewModel = new certViewModel();    
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

I think you were way overthinking this, unless you were triyng to do something really specific?

https://jsfiddle.net/1vu0skpg/5/